# Issue with rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller pages as follow:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def login
  end

end
```

i have the views corresponding also , and in my routes.rb, i have the following

```
devise_for :users

  get 'log in' => 'pages#login'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'


  root :to => 'pages#home'
```

when i try to go to the login page it's gave me an error :

undefined local variable or method `login_path' for #<#:0x2b9a298>

i try to match the controller to the actions ,same error . i'm new with rails , i'm trying to understand what i did wrong , because it works for the 'about' page. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes should be:

```
match 'login', :to => "pages#login", :as => :login
match 'about', :to => "pages#about", :as => :about
```

To learn more about Rails routing, check out the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: this way i 'm gonna have the login_path helper to use in the views?

Comment: Yes, although `login_url` is the usual convention.

Answer (score 1):

```
get 'log in' => 'pages#login'
```

Is there a space in "log in" or is that just how it appears here?

I think Devise also has some special setup in how you customize the routes. Here is an example provided on their GitHub page:
    devise_for :users, :path => "auth", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }

It's at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise under Configuring Routes.

Comment: i checked the configuring routes ,  what i'm trying to is : i have a controller pages with a login action ,this login action is just the name of the page., there's nothing to do with devise , all the devise view works fine , but in the login page, i'm going to render some devise views via partials.